# Incompatible types, found List<capture<? extends Model>> only in Java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, rx-java2

I'm currently reviewing changes to an Android application that upgrade the app to use Java 8.

During review, I noticed the following code was underlined as an error:

```
List<MappableTask> tasks = Observable.fromIterable(taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks())
        .filter(isMappableTask)
        .toList()
        .blockingGet();
```

This is now showing the following:

```
Incompatible Types.
Required: List<MappableTask>
Found: List<capture<? extends MappableTask>>
```

The `getMappableTasks()` method is defined in an interface as the following:

```
List<? extends MappableTask> getMappableTasks();
```

Note that `MappableTask` is an interface implemented by various model classes.

How is it that `List<MappableTask> list = taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks();` is not valid?

This code builds as expected. As stated, this error was not shown before upgrading the application to use Java 8. Why is this issue occurring?

Comment: Short answer: assuming B extends A, List<B> is not subtype of List<A>

Answer (score 5):

Your interface declaration allows `getMappableTasks` method to return list of any `MappableTask` subclass. Assuming `MappableAsyncTask` extends `MappableTask` your interface theoretically can return `List<MappableAsyncTask>`.

```
class MappableAsyncTask extends MappableTask {
}

class AsyncPresenter implements TaskMapHoldingPresenter {
    @Override
    public List<? extends MappableTask> getMappableTasks() {
        List<MappableAsyncTask> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new MappableAsyncTask());
        return result;
    }
}
```

But `List<MappableAsyncTask>` is not a subclass of `List<MappableTask>`, so you can't assign `getMappableTasks` result to `tasks` variable.

```
List<MappableTask> tasks = asyncPresenter.getMappableTasks(); // wrong
```

This restriction exists for a reason. If this assignment was possible you could easily add `MappableTask` instance into `tasks` list, breaking actual list implementation contract. Remember that actual list which was returned by `getMappableTasks` method can contain only instances of `MappableAsyncTask`.

```
List<MappableTask> tasks = asyncPresenter.getMappableTasks(); // wrong
tasks.add(new MappableTask()); // wrong
```

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Comment: You can preclude wrong insertions by using `List<MappableTask> tasks = Collections.unmodifiableList(asyncPresenter.getMappableTasks());`, which then also allows the type transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
List<MappableTask> tasks
    = Observable.<MappableTask>fromIterable(taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks())
        .filter(isMappableTask)
        .toList()
        .blockingGet();
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177411/2711488) correctly explains, you can not simply assign a `List<? extends MappableTask>` to `List<MappableTask>`, as that would break type safety, i.e allow insertion of wrong elements.

So an assignment of

```
List<MappableTask> list = taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks();
```

is never valid, but note that you can use a collection of a super type if you can preclude such insertions, i.e.

```
List<MappableTask> list // just a lightweight wrapper
    = Collections.unmodifiableList(taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks());
```

Likewise, creating a copy is valid

```
List<MappableTask> list = new ArrayList<>(taskMapHoldingPresenter.getMappableTasks());
```

as it can’t modify the original list.

And you are creating an `Observable` that will only read elements and chaining operations that will eventually create a new list, so there is no problem if the new list’s type is `List<MappableTask>`.

But your compiler inferred the type `Observable<? extends MappableTask>` for the result of `fromIterable` which propagates through the chain, ending up with the result type
`List<? extends MappableTask>`. By inserting the explicit element type `<MappableTask>`, we create an `Observable<MappableTask>` and the result type will be `List<MappableTask>`. This works, as `fromIterable` accepts iterables returning elements of a more specific type.

Since the type inference has been changed between Java 7 and Java 8, it’s possible that the previous compiler inferred `Observable<MappableTask>` and the current infers `Observable<? extends MappableTask>`. I’m not going to judge which behavior is correct in each version, the formally correct behavior sometimes contradicts the intuition, but when using the explicit type as shown above, it should work in both versions with all compilers.